# Streamlining data loading in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have an Access database that I use for reporting. After I do the initial load of raw data, I have to run some create-queries to create some cache tables (to make forms run faster) and then run some updates on some secondary tables. If requested, I run a macro that creates almost a dozen of these look-up tables.

The problem I face is that executing these statements always results in a dialogue box asking me to confirm that running the create-query will delete the old table, warning me that there is not enough disc space / memory to undo (I think this is an internal Access problem, my workstation has plenty of physical resources), asking me if I *really* want to pase 1485672 rows into a new table... and it does this for every query. Is there any way to set a default answer for all of these statements so I can just execute the main macro and walk away for half an hour, instead of stitting and baby-sitting the stream of dialogue boxes? Ideally, I'd like to see the output in a console window or log file but I don't know if that is easily done.

Some of the create-table queries are execute directly from the macro, but some have more logic and are executed in code (`DoCmd.RunSQL "..."`). I have this problem with both types of queries. Same problems with update statements (as update-queries and also executed as SQL in code), and also with deletes.

Comment: You can set warnings off, but this will apply to all databases on the PC,m so it is important to set them on again. It is often best to execute queries, but how it all works depends on your code.

Comment: @Remou: I have this problem (too many dialogues) even when statements are executed in code, using  `DoCmd.RunSQL "Select blah into new_table from big_table"`

Comment: That uses `RunSQL`, not `Execute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute:

```
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDB

db.Execute "Select blah into new_table from big_table", dbFailOnError
```

You will not get (most?) warnings.

As a bonus, you can check records affected.

Comment: This looks promising. From what I've now read, I'll have to add some transaction commit/rollback handling code, and I will lose the progress bar at the bottom, but I think those two might be worth the fewer nuisance dialogues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SetWarnings` macro action, documented here:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177386%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Note that set warnings affects all the databases on the PC, not just the database in which the command is used. It is unsafe.

Comment: It's probably worse in macros than in code. Wrapping a code block with Setwarnings false and afterwards true is a common use if you know that the code will raise a warning you want to suppress or show different.